# Using Case results in where clause - i would like to use the results of TorL - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

```
DECLARE @TodayDayOfWeek INT
DECLARE @EndOfPrevWeek DateTime
DECLARE @StartOfPrevWeek DateTime
DECLARE @EndOfThisWeek DateTime
DECLARE @StartOfThisWeek DateTime
```

--Delcared the Parameters

```
SET @TodayDayOfWeek = datepart(dw, GetDate())
SET @EndOfPrevWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())
SET @StartOfPrevWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek+6), GetDate())
SET @StartOfThisWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())+1
SET @EndOfThisWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())+7
```

--Set the parameters dates to use for this week or last week

```
select st.SALESID
    ,   st.SALESNAME
    ,   st.CUSTACCOUNT
    ,   st.CUSTOMERREF
    ,   st.SALESSTATUS
    ,   cast (sl.LINENUM as decimal (18,0))
    ,   sl.ITEMID
    ,   cast (sl.SALESQTY as decimal (18,0))
    ,   cast (sl.LINEAMOUNT as decimal(18,2))
    ,   case when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfPrevWeek  and @EndOfPrevWeek 
then 'L'
when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfThisWeek and @EndOfThisWeek
then 'T'
End 'TorL'

from salestable st
inner join salesline sl
on st.SALESID = sl.SALESID

where st.DATAAREAID = 'fr'

order by TorL
```

TorL is the case results, I would like to filter this using where, to only show where T or L is T for this week or L for last week.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'TorL'`.

Comment: have you tried: where st.DATAAREID= 'fr' AND st.CREATEDDATETIME BETWEEN @StartOfPrevWeek AND @EndOfThisWeek?

Comment: the report is to determine whether the order was places this week, or last week (any older is irrelevant) so I need to flag T or L to filter by. if I do it between start of previous week and end of this week it will show all T and L's. I hope that clarifys that

Comment: actually it doesn't if you are filtering the data to just this week and last week, why do you expect it will show all dates?

Comment: the query I wanted, as answered by jyparask below, was to flag T for this weeks date range or L as last weeks date range on all sales orders, I then use reportbuilder to create a report with the T or L as the parameter (T as default parameter) which auto runs and emails to a rep. but if it fails for whatever reason, we can go back in and run it again for L if the date has changed to last week. this is because the rep is too lazy to chose a date range on his report! thanks for your help anyway but its sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(

    select st.SALESID
        ,   st.SALESNAME
        ,   st.CUSTACCOUNT
        ,   st.CUSTOMERREF
        ,   st.SALESSTATUS
        ,   cast (sl.LINENUM as decimal (18,0)) AS LINENUM 
        ,   sl.ITEMID
        ,   cast (sl.SALESQTY as decimal (18,0)) AS SALESQTY 
        ,   cast (sl.LINEAMOUNT as decimal(18,2)) AS LINEAMOUNT 
        ,   case when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfPrevWeek  and @EndOfPrevWeek 
    then 'L'
    when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfThisWeek and @EndOfThisWeek
    then 'T'
    End Torl

    from salestable st
    inner join salesline sl
    on st.SALESID = sl.SALESID

    where st.DATAAREAID = 'fr'

)

SELECT * 
FROM MyCTE
WHERE
Torl = 'T'
```

Comment: This is perfect once I realised I hadn't given the columns a column name (the fields with the decimal casting). thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

The nasty way to do this would be to just add the conditions for setting 'T' or 'L' to your WHERE clause:

```
DECLARE @TodayDayOfWeek INT
DECLARE @EndOfPrevWeek DATE
DECLARE @StartOfPrevWeek DATE
DECLARE @EndOfThisWeek DATE
DECLARE @StartOfThisWeek DATE
--Delcared the Parameters

SET @TodayDayOfWeek = datepart(dw, GetDate())
SET @EndOfPrevWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())
SET @StartOfPrevWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek+6), GetDate())
SET @StartOfThisWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())+1
SET @EndOfThisWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())+7

select st.SALESID
    ,   st.SALESNAME
    ,   st.CUSTACCOUNT
    ,   st.CUSTOMERREF
    ,   st.SALESSTATUS
    ,   cast (sl.LINENUM as decimal (18,0))
    ,   sl.ITEMID
    ,   cast (sl.SALESQTY as decimal (18,0))
    ,   cast (sl.LINEAMOUNT as decimal(18,2))
    ,   case when CAST(st.CREATEDDATETIME AS DATE) between @StartOfPrevWeek  and @EndOfPrevWeek 
then 'L'
when CAST(st.CREATEDDATETIME AS DATE) between @StartOfThisWeek and @EndOfThisWeek
then 'T'
End 'TorL'

from salestable st
inner join salesline sl
on st.SALESID = sl.SALESID

where st.DATAAREAID = 'fr'
AND (CAST(st.CREATEDDATETIME AS DATE) between @StartOfPrevWeek  and @EndOfThisWeek)

order by TorL
```

EDIT: Making the variables DATETIME can cause unwanted issues where you eliminate certain dates just because of the timestamp.  For this solution, it is recommended to make the variables of type DATE, and then CAST the st.CREATEDATETIME AS DATE.

Comment: since prevweek and thisweek are contiguous, you just need between startofprevweek and endofthisweek.

Comment: If they were DATE variables yes, but they are DATETIME so this is not necessarily true (e.g. if st.CREATEDATETIME is also DATETIME).  It raises a good point though that the variables should probably be of type DATE and the st.CREATEDATETIME should be cast as DATE too.

Comment: Well, I would hope they want the records counted that might fall on that final day of the previous week, that's another logic problem not being addressed by the question though.  I usually don't like between and would rather use >= startdate and < enddate + 1 (if both have 0 time) to make sure I get all the records correctly. *shrug*

Comment: You should fix your example to handle the datetime probs to help the OP, this is probably the simplest fix. +1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I agree about the date logic and updated my solution to avoid the trouble with time :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause at same level as it is defined.  Just use a subquery or CTE:

```
with t as (
      <your query here without the `order by`>
     )
select t.*
from t
where torl in ('L', 'T')
order by torl;
```

As a note:  do not use single quotes to escape column identifies.  Although allowed, it tends to lead to confusion.  In this case, you don't need any escape characters at all.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * 
from (
    select st.SALESID
        ,   st.SALESNAME
        ,   st.CUSTACCOUNT
        ,   st.CUSTOMERREF
        ,   st.SALESSTATUS
        ,   cast (sl.LINENUM as decimal (18,0))
        ,   sl.ITEMID
        ,   cast (sl.SALESQTY as decimal (18,0))
        ,   cast (sl.LINEAMOUNT as decimal(18,2))
        ,   case when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfPrevWeek  and @EndOfPrevWeek 
    then 'L'
    when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfThisWeek and @EndOfThisWeek
    then 'T'
    End 'TorL' 'Name'

from salestable st
inner join salesline sl
on st.SALESID = sl.SALESID

where st.DATAAREAID = 'fr'


) t
where Name = 'T' or name = 'L'
```

order by TorL

Comment: You need to name subquery or it will not work, right? And the order by must be outside the subquery.

Comment: still need to remove quotes from `'Torl'` and remove `'Name'`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an answer that not uses CTE or subqueries. In this cases you can use `CROSS APPLY`, that allows you to use the defined field right in your query. It makes the query more elegant.

```
select st.SALESID
    ,   st.SALESNAME
    ,   st.CUSTACCOUNT
    ,   st.CUSTOMERREF
    ,   st.SALESSTATUS
    ,   cast (sl.LINENUM as decimal (18,0))
    ,   sl.ITEMID
    ,   cast (sl.SALESQTY as decimal (18,0))
    ,   cast (sl.LINEAMOUNT as decimal(18,2))
    ,   N.TorL
from salestable st
inner join salesline sl
on st.SALESID = sl.SALESID
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT case when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfPrevWeek  and @EndOfPrevWeek then 'L'
               when st.CREATEDDATETIME between @StartOfThisWeek and @EndOfThisWeek then 'T'
          End
   ) N(TorL)
where st.DATAAREAID = 'fr'
AND N.TorL = 'L'
order by N.TorL
```

A simplified demonstration of `CROSS APPLY` applied to your question can be found in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9afda/1/0) here